# Reuse lowest_layer socket in another BOOST SSL Socket

Tags: c++, ssl, boost

I create pool connection of non-ssl sockets, it works fine. The general idea is accumulate native handles and reuse these. I call boost::socket::assign method to put native handle into boost socket class and work with it like usually.
But now I would like to upgrade this pool. I try to made this trick with  ssl::stream.lowest_layer().assign but it does not work.

Does anybody knows how to make it work ?

Comment: Why not simply store the actual object in the pool?

Comment: Because It takes a lot of resources than native handle.

Comment: Did you measure it? And besides, it might take resources, but it also gives you functionality (like binding to an executor which could imply allocator/strand) and just general RAII correctness. I'd be surprised if `socket` had a size over 3 ints.

Comment: Mmm. Indeed the service implementation type is a tuple of (socket fd, state, per-descriptor data). That's three "ints". I surmise that [due a compiler formality some opportunity for empty-base class is missed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547290/is-the-empty-base-optimization-in-gcc-configurable) and you get one extra byte offset, which with ABI aligning means one extra machine-register width extra:  https://wandbox.org/permlink/bCYjaliZR8mM1glH (boost 1.63). Sadly it doesn't seem the situation improved for Boost 1.70: https://wandbox.org/permlink/xlYpn6kQ8mPbxxhz

Comment: Thx for answer, but my question was not about how use ssl socket object and what it is, my question is how to assign native handle to ssl::stream and it would worked.